# Как привязать callback_data к Replykeyboardmarkup?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Создаю телеграм бота для практики и столкнулся с проблемой. Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку **в меню** выдавало рандомное аниме, но у меня не получается привязать callback_data к Replykeyboardmarkup. Кто знает как это исправить?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random


bot = telebot.TeleBot()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def helping(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_random_isekai =types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рандомное аниме исекай", callback_data="random_isekai")
    item_random_comedy =types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рандомное аниме комедия", callback_data="random_comedy")
    markup.add(item_random_isekai,item_random_comedy)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Кнопки снизу", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def anwser(call):
    if call.data == "random_isekai":
        way = "RandomAnime\Random_Anime_Isecai"
        animelist = ["Врата: Там бьются наши воины","Военная хроника маленькой девочки",
                     "Дьявол работает на неполный рабочий день","С нуля: Пособие по выживанию в альтернативном мире",
                     "Богиня благословляет этот прекрасный мир","Нет игры — нет жизни",
                     "Восхождение Героя Щита", "О моём перерождении в слизь","Герой-рационал перестраивает королевство",
                     "Реинкарнация безработного",]
        photo_id = [way +"\Jates.png",way +"\evilGirl.jpg", way+"\Podraborka.jpg",way +"\Re_Zero.jpg",
                    way +"\seless.jpg",way +"\Game.jpg",way +"\Gateup.jpg", way +"\Slime.jpg",
                    way +"\Hero.jpg",way +"\homeless.jpg"]
        a =random.randint(0, 9); b = a;   c = photo_id[a]
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        item_random_isecai = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рандомное аниме исекай ", callback_data="random_isekai")
        item_random_comedy = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рандомное аниме комедия ", callback_data="random_comedy")
        markup.add(item_random_isecai,item_random_comedy)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, open(c, "rb"), caption=animelist[b], reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == "random_comedy":
        way = "RandomAnime\Random_Anime_Comedy"
        animelist = ["Ванпанчмен", "Госпожа Кагуя: в любви как на войне", "Моб Психо 100",
                     "Дракон-горничная Кобаяши","Гинтама","Ох уж этот экстрасенс Сайки Кусуо!",
                     "Класс превосходства","Я - Сакамото, а что?", "Бродячие псы", "Необъятный океан"]

        photo_id = [way + "/OnePunch.png", way + "/Kaguya.png", way + "/Mob.png", way + "/Koba.jpg",
                    way + "/Gintama.jpg", way + "/Saiki.jpg", way + "/Class_of_Elite.jpg", way + "/Sakamoto.jpg",
                    way + "/Dogss.jpeg", way + "/Oceann.jpg"]
        a = random.randint(0,9); b = a; c = photo_id[b]
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        item_random_comedy = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рандомное аниме комедия ", callback_data="random_comedy")
        item_random_isecai = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рандомное аниме исекай ",callback_data="random_isekai")
        markup.add(item_random_comedy,item_random_isecai)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, open(c, "rb"), caption=animelist[b],reply_markup=markup)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Для использования callback нужна другая клавиатура.

```
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    mardup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Текст кнопки', callback_data=f'callback'))

отправлять клавиатуру
    bot.send_message(chat_id=12345, text=text, reply_markup=markup)
```

upd к коменту

С обычной кнопки отправить сообщение с инлай кнопкой

```
def send_inline(message):
    text = 'Нажмите на инлайн кнопку'
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    mardup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Текст кнопки', callback_data=f'callback'))
    return bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text=text, reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Тогда как сделать так чтобы обычная кнопка ссылалась на inline кнопку?

Comment: поправил ответ так понятнее?